# How to build .NET code on the Raspberry Pi with Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, raspberry-pi, mono, raspberry-pi-zero

I've installed `mono-complete` package on a Raspberry Pi Zero.  I am able to build single .cs files, but not projects.  Specifically, the following works:

```
mcs foo.cs
mono foo.exe
```

When a try to build a project (as below), it finishes fine, says build succeeded.  However, there aren't any new files or directories created.  If it did build, I have no idea where the files went.

```
xbuild /p:Configuration=Release project.csproj
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for those who might encounter this problem.
Turns out `xbuild` generates the build in a parallel directory called Builds.  It creates the following:

```
src   <-- my source code
Builds
    Debug
        myexec.exe
```